# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclyp'

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

import rclyp

from rclyp.node import Node

def main(args = None):
    rclyp.init(args = args)
    node = Node("py_test")
    node.get_logger().info("Hello ROS2")
    rclyp.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hi I am new at ROS2 trying to use this code but my terminal says  :

```
> user@user-VirtualBox:~/ros2_ws/src/my_py_pkg/my_py_pkg$
> ./my_first_node.py  Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/home/user/ros2_ws/src/my_py_pkg/my_py_pkg/./my_first_node.py", line 3, in <module>
>     import rclyp ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclyp'
```

I have tried [this link](https://answers.ros.org/question/355064/ros2-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-rclpy_rclpy/) but It doesn't look like same error like I got.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410708/modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named-%27rclyp%27/) by [fkaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/128287/fkaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name of the Python client library for ROS 2 is `rclpy`.

You have:

```
import rclyp
```

you'll have to update all references to `rclyp` and replace them by `rclpy`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fkaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/128287/fkaan/) on 2022-12-20**:
sleep is a important think. Thank you a lot